# CUDA 5.5 nvlink undefined reference (inheritance)

Tags: c++, inheritance, cuda, raytracing

I've been working on my GPU-raytracer implementation, but as I am new to CUDA I have some problems with compiling and linking the separate .cu files.
My 2 classes: Shader and Lambert. Lambert inherits the interface Shader. When I compile I recieve the following errors:

```
Error 4 error MSB3721: The command ""G:\Development\CUDA Toolkit\CUDA Toolkit v5.5\bin\nvcc.exe"
-dlink -o "Debug\CUDA RayTracer.device-link.obj" -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /Od /Zi /RTC1  
/MDd  " -L"P:\My Projects\CUDA Ray-Tracer\CUDA RayTracer\ThirdParty\SDL\lib\x86" -L"P:\My 
Projects\CUDA Ray-Tracer\CUDA RayTracer\CUDA RayTracer\\..\ThirdParty" -L"G:\Development\CUDA
Toolkit\CUDA Toolkit v5.5\lib\Win32" cudart.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib
comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib 
SDL.lib SDLmain.lib  -gencode=arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -G --machine 32 Debug\Camera.cu.obj 
Debug\IShader.cu.obj Debug\Lambert.cu.obj Debug\Matrix.cu.obj Debug\Plane.cu.obj 
Debug\sdl.cu.obj Debug\cuda_renderer.cu.obj" exited with code -1.   
C:\Program Files(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\BuildCustomizations\CUDA 5.5.targets  668


1>nvlink : error : Undefined reference to '_ZN6ShaderD1Ev' in 'Debug/IShader.cu.obj'
1>nvlink : error : Undefined reference to '_ZN6ShaderD0Ev' in 'Debug/IShader.cu.obj'
1>nvlink : error : Undefined reference to '_ZN6ShaderD2Ev' in 'Debug/Lambert.cu.obj'
```

I have no idea what '_ZN6ShaderD1Ev' means, I think everything is correct in my implementation (C++ wise, not sure what CUDA thinks about it). As far as I know CUDA 5.5 supports virtual functions and inheritance.

I have installed CUDA 5.5 Toolkit and I have enabled the "Generate Relocatable Device Code" in my Visual Studio 2012. Also I've set 'compute_30,sm_30'in order to use 'operator new' (my graphics card is capable of it - GTX670MX). My project consists only of .cu and .cuh files.

My source code:

```
//IShader.cuh
#ifndef I_SHADER_H
#define I_SHADER_H

#include "Vector3D.cuh"
#include "Color.cuh"
#include "IGeometry.cuh"

__device__ extern Vector cameraPos;
__device__ extern Vector lightPos;
__device__ extern Color lightColor;
__device__ extern float lightPower;
__device__ extern Color ambientLight;

class Shader
{
protected:
     Color _color;

public:
    __device__ Shader(const Color& color);

    __device__ virtual ~Shader();
    __device__ virtual Color shade(Ray ray, const IntersectionData& data) = 0;
};

#endif

//IShader.cu
#include "IShader.cuh"

__device__ Shader::Shader(const Color& color)
{
   this->_color = color;
}

// Lambert.cuh
#ifndef LAMBERT_H
#define LAMBERT_H

#include "IShader.cuh"

class Lambert : public Shader
{
public:
    __device__ Lambert(const Color& diffuseColor);
    __device__ Color shade(Ray ray, const IntersectionData& data);
};

#endif

//Lambert.cu
#include "Lambert.cuh"

Vector cameraPos;
Vector lightPos;
Color lightColor;
float lightPower;
Color ambientLight;

__device__ Lambert::Lambert(const Color& diffuseColor)
    : Shader(diffuseColor)
{
}

__device__ Color Lambert::shade(Ray ray, const IntersectionData& data)
{
    Color result = _color;

    result = result * lightColor * lightPower / (data.p - lightPos).lengthSqr();
    Vector lightDir = lightPos - data.p;
    lightDir.normalize();

    double cosTheta = dot(lightDir, data.normal);
    result = result * cosTheta;

    return result;
}
```

If you need more code I could give you link to github repo. 
I hope you can help me.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try [c++filtjs](http://pear.warosu.org/c++filtjs/) online demangler. `_ZN6ShaderD1Ev` means `Shader::~Shader()`.

Comment: OMG such a noobish mistake, that helped me really a lot. Indeed it was the destructor that I didn't define. Thank you very much !

Comment: @JackOLantern if you write up an answer I will upvote it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ enables different entities (e.g., functions) named with the same identifier to belong to different namespaces. To uniquely resolve names, the compiler uses *name mangling*, that is, it encodes additional information in the name of the involved entities. This is the reason why `nvlink` is referring to this "obscure" entity `_ZN6ShaderD1Ev`. In order to restore a more understandable name, a *demangling* operation is necessary.

Although demangling software exist, I'm often using an online demangler

[c++filtjs](http://pear.warosu.org/c++filtjs/)

Using this page, you can discover that

```
_ZN6ShaderD1Ev
```

actually means

```
Shader::~Shader()
```

which, in turn, suggests that you are not defining the destructor for the `Shader()` class.